# HTML Logic Form Obfuscating Password

Tags: javascript, html, web

I'm attempting to troubleshoot a login issue on an old system that noone here is very familiar with. We have what we believe to be the admin password, but it isn't working. I'm just grasping, but I thought maybe a browser issue, considering how old the system is, so I tried using Postman to see what kind of response I get, which resulted in a failure.

However, I'm noticing now that they seem to be using some method to obfuscate the password, and I don't really understand what it's doing.

The login form method is this.

```
<form method="post" name='login' action="/?language=en" onsubmit="document.getElementById('submit').disabled = true; document.getElementById('pass').value = CJMaker.makeString(document.getElementById('pass').value);" >
```

and the CJMaker file contains this.

```
function CJMaker(e)
{}function _CJMaker_makeString(val)
{if (val == null)
{return val;}var size = val.length;var retVal = new String();var conVal = new String();for (var i = 0; i < size; i++)
{var current = val.charCodeAt(i);current = current^4;conVal += String.fromCharCode(current);}for (var i = size - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{retVal += conVal.charAt(i);}return retVal;}CJMaker.makeString = _CJMaker_makeString;
```

So it looks like it's just using char codes, and I suspect that the password in the database isn't the actual password, but instead is whatever this would create.

I'm afraid I just do not understand this well enough to reverse it. I'm sure it's simple to some of you javascript guys though.

Can anyone tell me more about what this is doing?

Comment: paste `jmi\`e` into the password field in db if your storing as plaintext or pass it through bcrypt etc if your storing it as bcrypt, then the password will be `admin`, i.e just run the password you think though this xor and then insert it into the db

Comment: If there's is any shred of valuable data associated with that application, and the application is available via the Internet, I would strongly suggest shutting it down immediately and porting the passwords to an actual secure password storage mechanism.

Comment: I agree. We're in the process of replacing it with a modern solution. I'm pretty sure this little obfuscation technique was their attempt at securing it. Obviously, it is not. If you look at what I was doing kinda in reverse, it's obvious why it isn't. Since it's passed plain-text someone can easily grab the password via arp poisoning or similar and then looking at the login form find the method that they're using, and, as Barmar explained, that same method can reverse it. It's pretty terrible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function XORs the character code of each character with `4`, and then reverses the result.

This function is its own inverse, so if you have an encoded password on the server, run the function on that to get what you need to type.

```js
function CJMaker(e) {}

function _CJMaker_makeString(val) {
  if (val == null) {
    return val;
  }
  var size = val.length;
  var retVal = new String();
  var conVal = new String();
  for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    var current = val.charCodeAt(i);
    current = current ^ 4;
    conVal += String.fromCharCode(current);
  }
  for (var i = size - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    retVal += conVal.charAt(i);
  }
  return retVal;
}
CJMaker.makeString = _CJMaker_makeString;

let instring = "abcdefgh";
let obfusc = CJMaker.makeString(instring);
let outstring = CJMaker.makeString(obfusc);
console.log(instring, obfusc, outstring);
```

Comment: Thank you. Been afk since op. Just got to check and this was very helpful. Unfortunately, it is mostly helpful in that it helps me to confirm that we don't have the correct password, but that's a step forward.